# laravel 5.0: The requested URL was not found

Tags: laravel-5

I created controller in /app/Http/Controllers/Hello.php by php artisan make:controller Hello

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class Hello extends Controller
{
//

public function index()
{
return 'hello world from controller : )';
}
}
```

And i added following code in  /app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('hello', 'Hello@index');
```

when i run my laravel app by http://localhost/laravel/public/

it display Laravel in center

but when i using http://localhost/laravel/public/hello
it generate "The requested URL /laravel/public/hello was not found on this server." Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable mod_rewrite and change folder permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel_folder
chmod -R o+w laravel_folder/storage
```